# why are asymmetric keys more secure?

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption

I'm trying to understand this page from Microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx.

According to the documentation "...they provide a higher level of security than symmetric encryption". I get that you first encrypt the data using symmetric and then encrypt that key using another method (symmetric or asymmetric) in order to avoid having to re-encrypt the data plus the speed benefits.

What I don't get is why choosing asymmetric over symmetric for that 2nd level is any more secure? Is it just because asymmetric can be then encrypted by the database master key? Is it possible to have one user encrypt data to another user on the same database then? I don't see what other advantage you would have within a database.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography rather than programming.

Comment: Not sure why the topic question was changed. My question was specific to how SQL Server asymmetric keys function among the users in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the absence of context on the referenced page I would assume they mean:

> In a symmetric key regime anyone who has **the shared secret** key can encrypt or decrypt anything. In asymmetric key use, there is no single shared secret.

As [Wikipedia notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm), the "…requirement that both parties have access to the secret key is one of the main drawbacks of symmetric key encryption…"

**added in response to comment**:

Suppose I have a datum `D` that I want to encrypt with a symmetric shared key. I compute `S(D)` to get `D'`. If you have the key needed to decrypt `D'`, you also have the key to compute `E ⇔ E'` where `E` and `E'` are any arbitrary plain- and cypher-text.

Contrariwise in asymmetric crypto, if I have used my secret key to compute `P(D)` to get `D''` all you have available to you is my public key which allows you to compute `Q(D'') → D` but `P(x)` is not available to you so you can't create new cyphertext. You can't use my private key because you don't have it. You cannot give away my secret or use it yourself because you never had it. This is what makes shared key (symmetric) cryptography fundamentally less secure than public key (asymmetric) crypto.

Comment: I get in terms of sending information to others why asymmetric is better in that regard. But inside SQL Server, who is the 2nd party? Is it just that other can encrypt information only decryptable by your account?

Comment: Thanks for the addition. From what I can see from within a SQL Server context, asymmetric keys must belong to a specific SQL Server login and therefore decryption can only happen from that account. Conversely a symmetric key can be used by several accounts. While it looks there is an AUTHORIZATION paramter for SQL symmetric keys, you really want to control this with a certificate or asymmetric key instead. I hope my understanding is right

Comment: I guess it really depends on if your encrypted information is for consumption by third parties, if not then the public key becomes less useful.